# Generating Back lInks

Tags: backlinks, local-seo

I am new to this field of SEO.  My site is intended to target local customers only.

I want to generate quality backlinks for my site. Is there any tools to generate quality backlinks. Or blog sites to improve count of backlinks.

I am trying to improve my page ranking .

Any Other SEO tips also would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get about the tool because they are not going to Good for you.

1. For local ranking try to host your website in same region or country.
2. Generate some back-link from locally hosted website
3. Participate in local communities / forum Get your local bloggers to
4. write about your business / product

Comment: can u elaborate this "Generate some back-link from locally hosted website"

Comment: The website which are using local IP address. Enter the website here and you will get the IP of the domain / hosting. If that IP address is referring to your region or country then its locally hosted domain for you.